# Vector not being Returned to Main Function

Tags: c++, vector

I am working on an exercise which entails feeding a vector of int values into a second function to be rearranged so that they are then in reverse order (so if I was feeding in 1, 2, 3, 4 the resulting output would be 4, 3, 2, 1)

```
// Workshop3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int reverse(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b)
{
int count = 0;
int end = a.size() - 1;

while (count < a.size())
{
    b.push_back(a[end]);
    count++;
    end--;
}

    return 1;
}

int main()
{

char blank;

//A simple int value for use in outputting the entire vector
int count = 0;

//Creates the initial vector
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

std::vector<int> rev;

std::cout << "Initial Vector \n";

//Outputs the vector onto the console
while (count < vec.size())
{
    std::cout << vec[count] << " ";

    count++;
}

std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << "Reversed";
std::cout << "\n";

reverse(vec, rev);

//Outputs the reversed vector
count = 0;

while (count < rev.size())
{
    std::cout << rev[count] << " ";

    count++;
}

std::cin >> blank;

return 0;
}
```

While the vectors are passed to the *reverse* function the information is not then returned to the main function after the reversal is completed. When ran the *reverse* function works as expected with the b vector being filled with the correct values in the correct order but this information is not being passed back to the **rev** vector in the main function as I would have expected.

I'm pretty sure its something I just haven't added to the code required to actually do this. Could anyone explain what I have done wrong.

If any more clarification is needed please let me know and I will try to elaborate as much as I can.

Comment: int reverse(std::vector<int> const & a, std::vector<int> & b)

Comment: Study up on passing by reference.

Comment: Except for punctuation and the spelling (but not necessarily meaning) of some keywords, C++ is very different from C#. There is a good book list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Don't skip over the things you think you already know.